Conjugate solutions to degree 4 equation
Let's say we want to find solutions to $(a+b \sqrt{d})^4 + (a-b\sqrt{d})^4 = 8$, where $a, b, d$ are rational.
When we expand this out, we get $a^4 + 6a^2 b^2d + b^4 d^2 = 4$, but I don't know how one would attempt to find rational solutions to this equation.
Any help is appreciated.

Your equation is a quadratic equation in $d$. A necessary condition for a rational solution is that $2a^4+1$ is a rational square. So for example $a=0$ gives a solution, namely $b=\pm 1$ and $d=2$.

Ljunggren theorem states that $n^2-2a^4=1$ has at most $2$ integer solutions (we found one $a=0$, is there another one ?). Also does this somehow extend to rationals ?

@zwim To be a bit more precise: Ljuggren's theorem states that there are at most two integer solutions in positive integers. It also states that if there are two such solutions $x_1+y_1^2\sqrt{d}$ and $x_2+y_2^2\sqrt{d}$, then one is the fundamental unit in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ and the other is either its square or its fourth power. As $1+\sqrt{2}$ is the fundamental unit in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ there is at most one solution in positive integers.

@Servaes Thanks for this information complement. I'm not too familiar with this.
